# Http Status Code 413

Tags: asp.net, https, iis-6

I have a page with normal Ajax Update panel. There is a submit button which sends the user selection to server. If the user waits for a minute or two, the response from the server is HTTP 413 ( request entity is too large) from server. This only happens when I try to resubmit it after waiting for a minute or two. If a land of the page and submit the form, the server is able to process it.

I have modified the uploadReadAheadSize(as mentioned http://forums.asp.net/t/1574804.aspx) and set it to 200,000,000 - still the problem persists

Http Request

```
POST https://server/somepage HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,zh-Hans;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh-SG;q=0.7,zh-Hant;q=0.6,zh-HK;q=0.4,zh-MO;q=0.3,zh-TW;q=0.2,zh;q=0.1
Referer: https://server/somepage
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
x-microsoftajax: Delta=true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)
Host: some-server
Content-Length: 86124
Connection: Keep-Alive
Form-Data...........
```

The request is over SSL.

I also tried to edit httpruntime configuration in web config

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1902400" />
```

Comment: Extremly Sorry. Setting the uploadReadAheadSize to 200 MB worked. I was earlier trying to set the size of about 2 MB. To keep it in safe range, modified it to 20 MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That solved the error. Correct me, if I am able to correctly describe the problem.

The SSL opens a secure tunnel for some time. So whenever I tried posting data in that time frame everything went fine. But once the tunnel got closed and server preloads the request before client re-negotiation. But preload max length was small and hence it failed.

I tried to set the value of uploadReadAhead value to 120,000 which was greater than the entity request size of about 86,000. Still the request failed (weird .. ????).

It was fine once I set it to the value of approx 10 MB.